# Need help formatting dates and text in a range of cell

Tags: formatting, cells

I've got a spreadsheet with certificates that expire at different dates. All of these have two columns. In one column is the date the certificate expires in which is usually every 3-5 years. The next column is the annual survey that is done for some, but not all certificates. In this column I have dates for some but N/A for others. PLEASE NOTE: this is not the #N/A error (which seems to come up in google searches for this)

My question is:
How do I format these cells to fill the cell red when they are expiring (or maybe yellow when they're getting close to expire) but leave all of the N/A text alone?

Thanks.

Comment: Use conditional formatting on the first column only with a condition that turns the cell fill red when the date value is smaller than the current date and yellow if current date minus expiry date is smaller than 31 (expires within the next month)